# How do I sort this list?

Tags: c#, python, ruby, sorting, haskell

I have a list of lists.

```
List<List<T>> li = {
   {a1,a2,a3 ... aN},
   {b1,b2,b3 ... bN},
   ...
};

double foo(List<T> list)
{
    // do something 
    // e.g {1,2,3} 
    // it = 1 + 2 + 3

    return it;
}
```

Now I want to sort `li` in such a way that higher the `foo(x)` for a `x` higher it should appear in a sorted list.

**What is the best way in C#/Python/any other lang to this?**

Comment: Why are you showing C# and asking about Python?  How does Python enter into this question?

Comment: @S. Lott I am currently coding in C# but I would also like to know how to do it in Python as it is my favorite lang!

Comment: Now that my basic purpose is served this could be code-golf also!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a little bit of LINQ:

```
var q = from el in li
        orderby foo(el)
        select el;
li = q.ToList();
```

Comment: How to do reverse sorting in LINQ?

Comment: I would start here: http://www.linqpad.net/ . Note that it comes pre-installed with a lot of samples.

Comment: Daniel, this was only marked 'Code Golf' briefly. And it is short enough.

Comment: li.OrderByDescending(elem => foo(elem)).ToList()

Answer (score 10):

The Haskell solution is particularly elegant with the [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Function.html#v%3Aon) combinator from Data.Function.

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

lists = [ [ 5, 6, 8 ]
        , [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        ]

main = do
  print $ sortBy (compare `on` foo) lists
  where
    foo = sum
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[5,6,8]]
```

There's also [`comparing`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html#v%3Acomparing) from Data.Ord that lets us instead write

```
main = do
  print $ sortBy (comparing foo) lists
  where
    foo = sum
```

The [definition of `comparing`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Ord.html#comparing) is a straightforward

```
comparing :: (Ord a) => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
comparing p x y = compare (p x) (p y)
```

but we could also define it in terms of `on`:

```
comparing :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
comparing f = compare `on` f
```

or completely point-free with

```
comparing :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
comparing = (compare `on`)
```

Haskell manipulates functions as powerfully as Perl manipulates strings.

Comment: Or use `sortWith`: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/GHC-Exts.html#v%3AsortWith

Comment: I should perhaps note: the purpose of `sortWith` is not really just to be a shortcut for `sortBy . comparing`, but actually to provide niceties for generalized list comprehension: `{-# LANGUAGE TransformListComp #-} [list | list <- lists, then sortWith by sum list]`

Answer (score 5):

This is the Python way: Just pass the function as the `key` argument to `sorted()` or `.sort()`:

```
>>> mylist = [123, 765, 4, 13]
>>> def mod5(x):
...     return x%5
...
>>> sorted(mylist, key = mod5)
[765, 123, 13, 4]
>>> sorted(mylist, key = mod5, reverse = True)
[4, 123, 13, 765]
```

Comment: That's fine :-) The C# solution is what helped you most, so you accepted the right one.

Comment: @david: I guess, if you have to put a label on it :-)

Comment: @Tor Valamo: That's true in this very example. But this was a question about how to use the function as a sorting key, not about when to use `def` vs. `lambda`. The actual use case might be more complicated than `x%5` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3],
             [3,5,9],
             [1,1,1],
             [10,23,14]]

sortedlist = mylist.sort {|a,b| b.inject {|sum, n| sum + n } <=> a.inject {|sum,n| sum + n}}
```

I'm not sure the rules of Code Golf and I didn't write a foo method, but the sum could easily occur in foo.

My test output:

```
puts sortedlist.inspect
```

[[10, 23, 14], [3, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: You can also do `li = li.sort_by {|i| foo(i) }.reverse` if performance isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, this is often done with the well-known [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
@li = map {$$_[0]} sort {$$a[1] <=> $$b[1]} map {[$_, sum(@$_)]} @li;
```

Reusing [Sort::Key](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Key) is better, though.

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
use Sort::Key qw(nkeysort);
@li = nkeysort {sum(@$_)} @li;
```

Comment: Of course, the naive expression `@li = sort {sum(@$a) <=> sum(@$b)} @li` works too, trading performance for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Any other language? Ok, here's some F#:

Example: sort by sum:

```
let foo = List.sum
let li = [[1;2];[42;1];[3;4]]

let result = li |> List.sortBy (fun el -> foo el)
```

Result (F# interactive):

```
val result : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [42; 1]]
```

Golfed:

```
let result = li |> List.sortBy (fun el -> foo el)
//shorter
let res = li |> List.sortBy foo
//evn shrtr
let r=List.sortBy foo li
```

The C# version:

```
var result = li.OrderBy(el=>el.Sum());
```

Answer (score 1):

in erlang:

```
-module (codegolfs).
-export ([sortmain/0]).

sortmain() ->
    sort( 
    fun (SubList) -> lists:sum(SubList) end,
    [ [1,2,3],[1,3],[2,5,6] ]).
    % output: [[2,5,6],[1,2,3],[1,3]]

sort(Fun,List) ->
    lists:sort( fun(A,B) -> Fun(A) < Fun(B) end,List ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby (shamelessly copying Beanish's input data):

```
list = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 5, 9],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [10, 23, 14]
]

p list.sort_by { |a| -a.inject(&:+) }
# => [[10, 23, 14], [3, 5, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Clojure:

```
(let [lst '((1 2 3)  (3 5 9) (1 1 1) (10 23 14))]   
 (sort #(> (foo %1) (foo %2)) lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt any of the popular sorting routines to do this. Just use foo(x) for comparison rather than x.

Comment: I don't want sorting technique. I want a way to express this effectively in the language.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl:

```
proc foo nums {tcl::mathop::+ {*}$nums}
set l {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {3} {42 -40}}
lsort -command {apply {{a b} {expr {[foo $a] - [foo $b]}}}} $l
# => {42 -40} 3 {1 2 3} {4 5 6}
```